# show webservice soapexception response in the client in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, soap-client, soapexception

I am trying to make a Test Webservice and throw a SoapException. But when I open the service through browser, it shows Internal server error - 500.

If i try to consume it manually by sending a manually created SoapRequest (in stringbuilder), I get the same error "Servererror - 500" in Visual Studio itself in the line "`WebResponse response = req.GetResponse()`"

Is there anyway I can actually see the "fault in response XML".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after surfing through for 5-6 hours finally got it......here it is:

When you are getting the response manually, use the following:

```
try
{
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();                
    Stream str = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(str);
    Response.Write(rdr.ReadToEnd());          
    Response.End();
}
catch (WebException webEx)
{
    Stream str = webEx.Response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(str); 
    Response.Write(rdr.ReadToEnd());          
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is something wrong with the service and you need to debug it on the server side rather than the client side. I come to this conclusion because you have a problem with your client code and a web browser.

Assuming you are using .NET have you enabled display of ASP.NET errors on the server? See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/customerrorsinaspnet.aspx) for info.

**Update:**

So you are throwing an error on the server and want to get the error text on the client? An error on the server is supposed to result in a 500 error message and is unlikely to return any XML to the client. Perhaps you can pass something to the SoapException constructor?

Have you looked at the [docs for SoapException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx)? They have some examples of passing information using the Detail property of SoapException.

Comment: the server code is just 
        [WebMethod]
        public void GetSoapException()
        {
            throw new SoapException();
        }

So there is no possibility of it being wrong.

Comment: Right...I can pass something to SoapException constructor (infact i have already tried it) but at the end I need to throw that exception...Am I wrong here?

Will throwing an exception always cause "server error - 500"? If so how can i get the fault in response XML.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get to the asmx (assuming you are using asmx) in the browser to see if it is working at all?

Comment: No its not working if I directly open the asmx from IE and invoke the method, the next screen I get is "HTTP 500 internal server error"